# Django Allauth Facebook Integration Login Failure

Tags: python, django, security, cryptography, django-allauth

I've successfully integrated Google, Instagram and Vkontakte with django-allauth, but having problems with Facebook.

Here is what happens:

- Click Login by Facebook Button on my website
- Browser redirects to Facebook website for login, and facebook requests - password.
- Facebook accepts the password
- Browser redirects back to my website but gives the following error: **"Social Network Login Failure, An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account."**
- Login failed

I have SSL certificate set up.

**Facebook Settings:**

- App Domains: example.com, www.example.com
- Client OAuth Login: Yes
- Web OAuth Login: Yes
- Embedded Browser OAuth Login: Yes
- Valid OAuth Redirect URIs: https://www.example.com/accounts/facebook/login/callback/
- Deauthorize Callback URL: https://www.example.com/

**Admin Settings:**

- Sites: example.com (SITE_ID = 3), www.example.com (SITE_ID = 2)
- settings.py: SITE_ID = 2

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding the following to settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL='https'
```

Answer (score 2):

I am in your same situation. It's been days and I cannot adjust this error.
This is my question on Stackoverflow: [How to fix 'Social Network Login Failure' error of django-allauth deployed on Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669538/how-to-fix-social-network-login-failure-error-of-django-allauth-deployed-on-el)

Edit: I saw your answer but it did not work for me, are you sure this was the only thing you changed to make it work?

Anyway, the value 'https' should be with quotes:

```
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'
```

Can you give more information about the changes you did in your code and configuration?

Comment: Yes, that's the only change I made. I suggest you to delete and create the Facebook app again from scratch. Also, make sure that you have the correct SITE_ID in the settings.py